# Image taken from ImageList looks different than taken straight from resource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a form with two buttons.

To one of them I assigned an image (a 16 x 16, 32 bit depth `png`) by setting the `Image` property from VS's properties editor (using the `Import...` button).

I also have an `ImageList` (16 x 16 `ImageSize` and `Depth32Bit` `ColorDepth`) to which I assigned the same image as to the first button also from the properties editor -> `Images` and then `Add`. Then I assigned this image to my second button this way:

```
button2.Image = imageList.Images[0];
```

And this is how the images look (2x the actual size):

[image]

Is it possible to have my second button look like my first one by using an `ImageList`? The reason why I use an `ImageList` is because when checking performance, the line of code that loaded the image from the resource was a hot spot according to VS's Performance Wizard.

My application will have a list of controls, each of which have a bunch of buttons with images, so I want them to load as fast as possible. So what I have is a static `ImageList` from which each of these controls get their images.

Comment: That's not a 16x16 image, it is at least 32x32.  Makes it likely that the documented ImageList.ColorDepth is wrong too which could explain the color loss.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's what Windows tells me when I double click -> Properties -> Details. Note that my image is 2x the actual size.

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @tunafish24 It was a long time ago but I think this stopped happening when I stopped editing the image with Photoshop. Never figured what exactly why this happened.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the images you have added in your Imagelist have higher ColorDepth that the ColorDepth you have set in your ImageList Properties. for example, if the images you have added are in PNG format, you should set the ColorDepth of you ImageList (In the properties window) to Depth32Bit as the PNG format uses 32Bit color depth.

Comment: My `ImageList` is set to 32 bit color depth. "_I also have an `ImageList` (16 x 16 `ImageSize` and `Depth32Bit` `ColorDepth`)..._"